# three.js - focus camera on THREE.Geometry vertices

Tags: three.js

1. I want to focus the camera on THREE.Geometry, one vertex at a time and
2. Transition the camera to the next vertex of the same Geometry

How should i accomplish 1 & 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5oajajpd/

the function move camera goes through each vertex and sets the camera position. To transition this with animation you can set the x,y, and z properties through the jquery animate function, or your animation lib of choice.

The move camera function is triggered by an interval. In this sphere example it will spiral around and around the sphere forever.

```
var i = 0;

function moveCamera() {
  var point = mesh.geometry.vertices[i];
  var coeff = 1 + altitude / rad;
  camera.position.x = point.x * coeff;
  camera.position.y = point.y * coeff;
  camera.position.z = point.z * coeff;
  camera.lookAt(mesh.position);
  i++;
  if (i > mesh.geometry.vertices.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case i have THREE.Geometry with a bunch of THREE.Vector3 vertices pushed to it. Is there a specific way to lookAt a Vector3 ?

Comment: Inthe example, mesh.position is vector3. Replace the camera.lookAt parameter with the vertex, the camera will point towards the vertex.

Comment: and that's exactly what i am unable to do. In my case, i have those vertices pushed to a Geometry that is part of a PointCloud that is added to an Object3D (which is finally added to the scene). Does this nesting result in problems such as the camera not able to lookAt those vertices?

Comment: Nope. Any vertex that is a valid Vector3 object will work in the camera.lookAt setter.

Comment: Here the camera does not move. a little sphere moves from vertex to vertex of the larger sphere. The camera points itself to always look at where the little sphere has moved to. http://jsfiddle.net/85nbo00p/ Check that you have pushed your vertices to the vertices object, check that there is only one object inside Object3d, and also check the origin point of your camera.

Comment: Great! I am marking this question as closed. Next, i add Stereoeffect and my lookAt no longer works. I asked a separate question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800799/three-js-camera-lookat-not-working-with-stereoeffect . Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: The question on this page doesn't have a controls object and we manipulate the camera directly. When using controls, the controls manipulate the camera. I have provided an answer at the new question.