# Camera lookAt not working with stereoeffect

Tags: three.js

When I use stereoeffect using the following code, how should I get my camera to lookAt a certain Vector3?

```
function animate() {
    var elapsedSeconds = clock.getElapsedTime();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    update(clock.getDelta());
    render(clock.getDelta());
  }

  function update(dt) {
    resize();
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    controls.update(dt);
  }

  function render(dt) {
    effect.render(scene, camera);
  }
```

I added camera.lookAt in my initialization code but I understand the `render(..)` function is constantly called and overrides my lookAt.

So, how do I correctly initialize the scene so that my lookAt point is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its more likely the controls update sending the camera back to it's own target. Try setting the controls target instead.

```
    var lookat = vertex; /// whatever Vector3 you are using already

    controls.target = lookat;
    controls.update();
```

Comment: life saver that. Thanks !

Comment: Is `controls.target` a `THREE.Vector3`? Then do not instantiate a new one every frame. `controls.target.copy( vertex )`.